# Can't compare SQL TEXT's with strings in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to make some kind of login system with MySQL in Python. I have some problems with comparing SQL TEXT's and strings. My table's querys are:

```
indexnum INT,
host TEXT,
name TEXT,
password TEXT,

INSERT INTO table VALUES (0, "localhost", "root", "");
```

Here is my Python code:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", database="accounts", user="root", password="")
cursor = connection.cursor()
host = input("--> ")

cursor.execute("USE accounts;")
cursor.execute("SELECT host FROM table ORDER BY indexnum;")

for i in cursor:
    if i == host:
        ...
```

if condition does not return true when for loop executes. I tried to print the `i` variable and got a tuple value as output `('localhost'),`. I tried to change the if statement like this `if i == "('localhost'),"` which was really a dumb idea and it did not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use proper variable names: What you get back from the cursor is not an "i", it's a *row*. `for row in cursor:` and `if row[0] == host`.

Comment: That being said, you typically don't select all rows from the database and then go through them one by one in Python code to see if any of them matches. You use a WHERE clause and query parameters to pass the value to the database and see if any records are returned.

Comment: And *that* being said, saving clear text passwords is a very bad idea, you should not do this outside of exercise code that will never go live anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Selecting the index number of tuple just solved my problem and I will be more careful about storing passwords too :)

Comment: That's not a question of "what type". You don't store passwords in the database *at all* - not as plain text, and not encrypted. Look up "salted hashes" to get an idea what you need to do for secure password handling. Tons of tutorials and discussion exist on the topic, there is something for every combination of language and database system.

Comment: Thank you so much again. Except the question I thank you for warning me. I will search up after I finish some parts in my code. Have a great day!